# Why am I not getting a table with the following code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let myLibrary = [
                  ["Title", "Author", "Pages", "Have you read the book"]
                  ["Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", "366", No],
                  ["My Test Book", "Myself", "50", Yes]
                ];

  function render(){
  let table = document.getElementById('table');
  for(let book in myLibrary){
   let row = table.insertRow();
    for(let bookInfo in book){
      let cell = row.insertCell()
      cell.innerHTML = bookInfo;
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting that I will get a table with the following code.
But I am gettin 0 as output. Can anyone find a solution for this ?

Comment: for...in is for iterating the keys of an object. Instead, you can use for...of to iterate the values of the array (also ensure your first array in `myLibrary` has a comma proceeding it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to iterate the arrays:

```
function render() {
  let table = document.getElementById("table");
  myLibrary.forEach(function (r) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    r.forEach(function (c) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.innerHTML = c;
    });
  });
}
```